# Função em TypeScript, trazer a resposta do usuario na tela após o click

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Olá. Pessoal eu tenho uma função onde eu carrego 3 botões de cores (amarelo,azul,preto) na minha tela, preciso que quando eu clico nesses botões em uma div embaixo apareça as cores que ele esta clicando.
Entao o comportamento esperado é que quando eu clicar no amarelo aparecer abaixo a cor amarelo, azul aparecer azul etc.
O comportamento que estou tendo é que quando eu clico nos botões ele traz o click porem sem a cor. Segue função e html.

```
loadSequencia(sequencia: String): void{
this.sequencia.push(sequencia);

console.log('sequencia', this.sequencia);
}
```

////html dos botões

<button (click)="loadSequencia('yellow')" style="background-color:
yellow; ">

<button (click)="loadSequencia('blue')" style="background-color:
blue;">

<button (click)="loadSequencia('black')" style="background-color:
black;">

////html da resposta dos botões

<li *ngFor="let sequencia of sequencia">

<button (click)="loadSequencia('sequencia')" style="background-
color: sequencia; ">

```
        </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu código, está faltando fazer a interpolação da variável na sua resposta.

```
<li *ngFor="let sequencia of sequencia;">
    <button
      (click)="loadSequencia(sequencia)"
      style="background-color: {{sequencia}};"
    >
      {{sequencia}}
    </button>
  </li>
```

No primeiro caso, só era necessário remover as aspas de `loadSequencia('sequencia')` para `loadSequencia(sequencia)`. Nesse caso não era necessário, pq já envolvia um evento `(click)`.

No caso do `style` e do trecho de dentro dos `<button>...</button>` é necessário a interpolação pois é uma interpretação do texto e não evento.
De `style="background- color: sequencia;"`, o correto seria definir como `style="background- color: {{sequencia}};"`.

No angular a interpolação de variáveis é feita através do uso das chaves duplas **`{{}}`**

O exemplo antes a explicação é a versão corrigida do trecho.

Comment: Obrigada, deu certo! :)